# doing sum two rows A and B, result in column c but getting error :-object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

```
'class module:- clscustomer
Public z As Integer
Public rng As Range
Public c As Range

Public Sub sum(x As Integer, y As Integer)

z = x + y
'error here
c.Offset(0, 2).Value = z \\error hereva

End Sub
```

Comment: where do you `Set c` ? you need something like `Set c = Range("A1")` , or whatever range you want to assign

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set c, you would only get the sum of the first row, you would have to put your code inside a loop; you could try to record a macro while performing the actions you want to accomplish; or use code that is a little more basic...

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("C2").Formula = "=SUM(A1,B1)"
    .Range("C2:C20").FillDown
End With
```